# UINavigationController strategy (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

Something is puzzling me, after going through my app with instruments, it is a UINavigationBased App, it noticed this.

Each time a tableView cell is tapped and I do this:

```
        GenericTableViewController *someViewController = [[Generic TableViewController alloc] init];    
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
        [someViewController release];
```

I then tap the back button and look in Instruments to see how many living instances of the GenericTableViewController there exists. There is 1 before the back tap, and 0 afterwards.
This is great, good clean memory management by the UINavigationController.

However, other places in the app I don't use the back button to leave a view, in some viewControllers tapping one of my custom buttons will run code completely like the above, but the viewController, in which I tapped the custom button, will not be released.

I guess I understand why, the navigationController makes a judgment call, that I might be pushing something on to the stack and that I will return later, so it keeps the controller in its memory. This must mean that tapping the back button uses a `[self.navigationController popViewController]`. Ok.

The problem is now that each time I visit a view that isn't left using a "back" button in the navigationBar, it
will not be released. The count allocation in Instruments just goes up each time I visit a view, until I have like 20 objects living.

I tried putting a `[self.navigationController popViewController]` in the selector for my custom buttons. Meaning that I manually pop the visible viewController before pushing a new on to the stack.
But the allocation count does not go down? guess the "back" button does not use this technic after all...

I also tried using popToViewController, since I always know if the controller has been on the stack or not. But to use the popToViewController, I need to keep a reference around for the view.

*Is there some sound way of saying to the UINavigationController: If this viewController is on your stack, please display it, if not please instantiate it, push to the stack and display it.*

The challenge here is probably that not all my navigation in the NavigationController is completely linear. I will sometimes have to go from stack item no. 2 to stack item no. 5, back to 3 etc.

**So is there a way to do this, while still having the UINavigationController making sure to release my viewControllers and not instantiating the same viewController several times?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to access `UINavigationController`'s [viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property to get a `NSArray` of all the view controllers currently on the navigation stack. Then use [containsObject:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:) to check if the view controller is already on the stack.
If it is, then use [popToViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:) to show the view controller. If it is not on the stack then just use [pushViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:).
If this does not help you, maybe [setViewControllers:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) is the right method.

Comment: Hi ChrisB
I did not think about using the array of viewcontrollers to manually test if my object is on the stack. Implemented correctly I should be able to make this test as few times as possible. Thanks